# Create a JTable that has a jCombobox in 2nd column which provides certain list of values depending on 1st column

Tags: java, swing

Create a `jTable` using `jCombobox` in 2nd column whose list of values varies with the item entered in the `1st column`
The row wise values in the `jCombobox` may vary depending upon the value entered in the `1st Column`

What i require is a simple solution to provide to the above question
Different `JComboBox` is required for each row in the second column

```java
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        int i = 0;
        jComboBox3.addItem("material1");
        jComboBox3.addItem("material2");
        String v5[] = new String[23];
        String v6[] = new String[23];
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();


        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(385, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(71, 71, 71))
        );

        pack();
        JTable jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {
                    v5[0], v6[0]
                }, {
                    v5[1],
                    v6[1]
                }, {
                    v5[2],
                    v6[2]
                }, {
                    v5[3],
                    v6[3]
                }, {
                    v5[4],
                    v6[4]
                }, {
                    v5[5],
                    v6[5]
                }, {
                    v5[6],
                    v6[6]
                }, {
                    v5[7],
                    v6[7]
                }, {
                    v5[8],
                    v6[8]
                }, {
                    v5[9],
                    v6[9]
                }, {
                    v5[10],
                    v6[10]
                },

            },
            new String[] {
                "Material",
                "Batch",
            }
        ));
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBox3));
        };
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBox8));
        };
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int j = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                String material = jTable1.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
                try {
                    jComboBox8.removeAllItems();
                    if (jComboBox3.equals("material1")) {
                        jComboBox8.addItem("1");
                    } else {
                        jComboBox8.addItem("2");
                    }
                } catch (Exception et) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, et);
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox8 = new javax.swing.JComboBox < > ();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox < > ();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 985, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 596, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTable` column "Product/Service" is a `JComboBox` and column "Batch" is also a `JComboBox` and the list of available batches is different for each product (or service). Hence whenever the user selects a product, you need to modify the displayed list of batches so that it matches the selected product, correct?

Comment: Correct for each product there may be different batches so JComboBox should be set for both columns but for the second column it would vary depending upon the product selected

Comment: I already did something very similar and implemented it via [Table Model Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html). Are you familiar with that listener?

Comment: I am not familiar with Table Model Listener, could you provide a modification to my code with that and explain.

Comment: I used a Table Model Listener but there is an issue with jComboBox which does not add the batches for the given materials separately, so I need to segregate each row jComboBox. Any idea to implement that

Comment: I suggest you post enough of your code to allow me to copy it, compile it and run it without having to modify it first. In other words, make sure the code you post compiles without error and runs in such a way that I can see your GUI displayed.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. There is no declaration for `jComboBox3` and `jComboBox8` and there is no method `initComponents()`.

Comment: The question is edited

Comment: Well, I guess we are making progress. You added the `initComponents()` method, but I still can't find the declaration for `jComboBox3` nor for `jComboBox8`.